# How to get the context of the current request in spring-webflux

Tags: spring-webflux

In the classic spring-mvc it is possible to set request scoped attributes on a `RequestContextHolder`. Building on that, we can parse an incoming request in a `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`, set request parameters such as currently logged in user, unique request ID (for log correlation) and so on.
These request attributes can be retrieved statically from **any service** (not only controllers) during the request's lifetime.

I am trying to achieve something similar with spring-webflux.

I could use a `WebFilter` to intercept all incoming requests, get the current `ServerWebExchange` and set attributes on it. However I don't see any way to get the current request's `ServerWebExchange` anywhere else other than controller methods.

I am looking for a better solution than passing `ServerWebExchange` (or `ServerHttpRequest`) all around.

It seems like this is difficult to achieve in webflux since we cannot rely on saving variables associated with a particular request on ThreadLocal (because of the non-blocking architecture, a single thread can switch between requests mid-flight).
Still, this is an important requirement. Maybe there is a different approach?

Comment: It's been almost 3 years. Has there been any update on this?

Comment: @AndrewTFinnell see this issue that I had opened at the time: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20239.
I have stopped following this issue because my team has moved from Spring-webflux back to Spring-MVC, but it looks like there has been some progress.

Comment: @DoronGold why did you move back to MVC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The approaches you're describing are the ones currently supported.
As you've underlined, using a static approach with `ThreadLocals` is not possible.

Reactor is looking into alternatives with a new context feature (see [this PR](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/pull/447)). Spring is likely to pick that up and use it, but not necessarily for request attributes since the current model fits quite well.

If you'd like a particular extension point to intercept requests, please create a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io) on the Spring Framework project, describing what you're trying to achieve and where things are failing.

Comment: You might want to look for inspiration in HATEOAS library - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/server/reactive/HypermediaWebFilter.java and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/server/reactive/WebFluxLinkBuilder.java