# How to get URL of the current controller method in Spring Webflux?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

This question is similar to [What's the best way to get the current URL in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490821/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-current-url-in-spring-mvc) but for Webflux (it might also be related to [How to get the context of the current request in spring-webflux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43975761/how-to-get-the-context-of-the-current-request-in-spring-webflux) but this question is more specific so I'm hoping there's a solution).

What I want to do is to get a hold of the current URL in a Webflux controller. For example:

```java
@GetMapping("/greeting")
public Mono<Greeting> greeting() {
   String linkToCurrentResource = .. // How do I get this?
   Greeting greeting = new Greeting("hello",  linkToCurrentResource);
   return Mono.just(greeting);
}
```

Preferably `linkToCurrentResource` should understand `X-Forwarded-???` headers if running behind a load balancer. So in this case the I'd like `linkToCurrentResource` to be something like `https://external-uri.com/api/greeting`. I'm using the Netty server implementation if that matters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`ServerHttpRequest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServerHttpRequest.html) as a method parameter to get the `uri`:

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {
  @GetMapping("/greeting")
  public Mono<Greeting> getGreeting(ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest) {
    return Mono.just(new Greeting("greeting", serverHttpRequest.getURI().toString()));
  }
}
```

> Preferably `linkToCurrentResource` should understand `X-Forwarded-???` headers if running behind a load balancer.

Then you can expose a [`ForwardedHeaderTransformer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/adapter/ForwardedHeaderTransformer.html) `@Bean`.

From its documentation:

> Extract values from "`Forwarded`" and "`X-Forwarded-*`" headers to override the request `URI` (i.e. `HttpRequest.getURI()`) so it reflects the client-originated protocol and address.

```
@Configuration
open class MvcConfig {
    @Bean
    open fun forwardedHeaderTransformer() = ForwardedHeaderTransformer()
}
```

---

Here are some tests:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT,
        properties = ["server.port=4333"])
class GreetingController2Test {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var restTemplate: TestRestTemplate

    @Test
    fun `should return uri`() {
        val responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity("/greeting", Greeting::class.java)
        val greeting = responseEntity.body!!
        assertEquals("http://localhost:4333/greeting", greeting.uri)
    }

    @Test
    fun `should return uri composed from forwarded-??? headers`() {
        val headers = HttpHeaders()
        headers["X-Forwarded-Host"] = "external-uri.com"
        headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"] = "https"
        headers["X-Forwarded-Prefix"] = "/prefix"

        val httpEntity = HttpEntity(null, headers)
        val responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("/greeting", HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, Greeting::class.java)
        val greeting = responseEntity.body!!
        assertEquals("https://external-uri.com/prefix/greeting", greeting.uri)
    }
}
```

And the `Greeting.kt`:

```
data class Greeting(
        val g: String? = null,
        val uri: String? = null
)
```

Comment: Thanks A LOT! I couldn't have hoped for better answer. Works like a charm.